# ¿Como crear Store Procedure dinámico, en SQLSERVER?

Tags: c#, sql-server

**Hola a todos, como debería crear una sentencia dinámica en SQL-SERVER que reciba un parámetro con la condicional IN.**

```
    create procedure spGenBK_Consultar_Masivo  
    @guia varchar(max),
    @Fecha char(6),    
    @Prod char(1) ,    
    @Cliente char(8),
    @CodReferenciaFac varchar(4) ='',
    @CodReferenciaweb varchar(4) = ''    

    as    
    select  
    gdn.pro_cod as Producto,    
    gn.guia_bill_pag_ref as Cliente,    
    gdn.guia_ano as OrdenAnio,    

    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = '00288710' and gdn.pro_cod = 'NAC'     
    then isnull(guia_orden_referencial,'')    
    else gdn.guia_nro    
    END as OrdenNro,     

    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = '00288710' and gdn.pro_cod = 'NAC'     
    then ''    
    ELSE isnull(guia_orden_referencial,'')    
    END as OrdenNroRef,    

    gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref as Guia,     
    convert(varchar, gdn.guia_det_fch_emi, 103) as FechaEmi,    
    replace(substring(gdn.GUIA_DET_CON_CIA,0,100),'''','') as Consignatario,     
    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = '00288710' and gdn.pro_cod = 'NAC'     
    then rtrim(gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref )    
    ELSE rtrim(gdn.guia_det_con_cuent_refer)    
    end as Cuenta,      

    guia_servicio as serviciocod,     
    ref_cod as ReferenciaCod,    
    ref_fac_cod as CenCostoCod,     
    gdd_new_imei as ImeiEntrega,    
    gdd_dev_imei as ImeiRecojo,    
    gdd_dev_telf as Telefono,     
    rtrim(isnull(guia_det_nro_master,'')) as Master,     
    gdn.guia_det_id as GuiaDetId        


    from guia_detalle_nacional as gdn WITH(NOLOCK)    

    join guia_nacional as gn WITH(NOLOCK)    
    on  gn.empr_cod = gdn.empr_cod    
    and gn.suc_cod = gdn.suc_cod    
    and gn.uni_neg_cod = gdn.uni_neg_cod    
    and gn.pro_cod = gdn.pro_cod    
    and gn.guia_ano = gdn.guia_ano    
    and gn.guia_nro = gdn.guia_nro    

    left join gdn_detalle as det WITH(NOLOCK)    
    on det.guia_det_id = gdn.guia_det_id    

    where  
    gdn.empr_cod = '00040007'    
    and gdn.uni_neg_cod = 'SLG'     
    and rtrim(gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref) in (@guia)--> ESTE es el campo que debe 
    aceptar varios datos('guia1','guia2',etc)
    and YEAR( gdn.guia_det_fch_emi) = @Fecha
    and gdn.pro_cod = case  @Prod                                     
    when '1' then 'NAC'                                      
    when '2' then 'MET'                                      
    when '3' then gdn.pro_cod                                      
    end     

    and gn.guia_shi_cod =@Cliente
    and isnull(gn.REF_FAC_COD,'')=case when @CodReferenciaFac='' then isnull(gn.REF_FAC_COD,'') else @CodReferenciaFac end
    and isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'')=case when @CodReferenciaweb='' then isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'') else @CodReferenciaweb end
```

**Intento llamar al SP así:**

```
spGenBK_Consultar_Masivo  (@guia='1011086828-1','1010968485-2'), 
@Fecha='2018',@Prod='1',@Cliente='00001342' ,@CodReferenciaweb='0439'
```

**Quiero que funcione como esta consulta:**

```
select  * from GUIA_DETALLE_NACIONAL with (nolock)
where rtrim(Guia_det_nro_ref) in ('1010968487-1','1010968485-2')
```

**Alguien puede ayudarme, para poder llamar a ese SP y tambien mandar los parámetros desde el C# Windows Form a SQL-SERVER.**

Gracias.

**TODO ESTO ES MI Store Procedure REAL, me puedes dar una mano para como modificar con los datos que me recomiendas.**

```
    create procedure spGenBK_Consultar_Masivo  
    @guia varchar(max),
    @Fecha char(6),    
    @Prod char(1) ,    
    @Cliente char(8),
    @CodReferenciaFac varchar(4) ='',
    @CodReferenciaweb varchar(4) = ''    

    as    
    select  
    gdn.pro_cod as Producto,    
    gn.guia_bill_pag_ref as Cliente,    
    gdn.guia_ano as OrdenAnio,    

    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = '00288710' and gdn.pro_cod = 'NAC'     
    then isnull(guia_orden_referencial,'')    
    else gdn.guia_nro    
    END as OrdenNro,     

    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = '00288710' and gdn.pro_cod = 'NAC'     
    then ''    
    ELSE isnull(guia_orden_referencial,'')    
    END as OrdenNroRef,    

    gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref as Guia,     
    convert(varchar, gdn.guia_det_fch_emi, 103) as FechaEmi,    
    replace(substring(gdn.GUIA_DET_CON_CIA,0,100),'''','') as Consignatario,     
    CASE WHEN GUIA_BILL_PAG_REF = '00288710' and gdn.pro_cod = 'NAC'     
    then rtrim(gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref )    
    ELSE rtrim(gdn.guia_det_con_cuent_refer)    
    end as Cuenta,      

    guia_servicio as serviciocod,     
    ref_cod as ReferenciaCod,    
    ref_fac_cod as CenCostoCod,     
    gdd_new_imei as ImeiEntrega,    
    gdd_dev_imei as ImeiRecojo,    
    gdd_dev_telf as Telefono,     
    rtrim(isnull(guia_det_nro_master,'')) as Master,     
    gdn.guia_det_id as GuiaDetId        


    from guia_detalle_nacional as gdn WITH(NOLOCK)    

    join guia_nacional as gn WITH(NOLOCK)    
    on  gn.empr_cod = gdn.empr_cod    
    and gn.suc_cod = gdn.suc_cod    
    and gn.uni_neg_cod = gdn.uni_neg_cod    
    and gn.pro_cod = gdn.pro_cod    
    and gn.guia_ano = gdn.guia_ano    
    and gn.guia_nro = gdn.guia_nro    

    left join gdn_detalle as det WITH(NOLOCK)    
    on det.guia_det_id = gdn.guia_det_id    

    where  
    gdn.empr_cod = '00040007'    
    and gdn.uni_neg_cod = 'SLG'     
    and rtrim(gdn.Guia_det_nro_ref) in (@guia)
    and YEAR( gdn.guia_det_fch_emi) = @Fecha
    and gdn.pro_cod = case  @Prod                                     
    when '1' then 'NAC'                                      
    when '2' then 'MET'                                      
    when '3' then gdn.pro_cod                                      
    end     

    and gn.guia_shi_cod =@Cliente
    and isnull(gn.REF_FAC_COD,'')=case when @CodReferenciaFac='' then isnull(gn.REF_FAC_COD,'') else @CodReferenciaFac end
    and isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'')=case when @CodReferenciaweb='' then isnull(gdn.REF_COD,'') else @CodReferenciaweb end
```

Comment: Se me ocurre que envies el primer parametro con los valores separados por coma, y dentro del stored procedure utilices un SPLIT para separar los valores en una tabla. Si usas SQL Server 2016 o posterior, la funcion es muy facil de usar: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Si te refieres a como llamar a un stored procedure desde el where, no se puede hacer. Para hacer lo que quieres hay diferentes formas, aquí te dan como ejemplo el uso de una tabla temporal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912623/how-to-use-where-clause-in-exec-stored-procdure

Comment: Hola **reekeecast**, tengo en una variable toda las lita, por ejemplo así: "'1010968487-1','1011086831-1','1011086832-1','1011086833-1'" que obtengo en el C#, solo me faltaría ver la manera de mandarlo a SQL Server  como parámetro.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es crear un tipo de datos en SQL Server:

```
 CREATE TYPE UDT_ARRAY AS TABLE(
      codigos varchar(50) NULL
  )
  GO
```

Este tipo de datos nos va a permitir enviarle al SP una tabla como parametro.

Después en tu SP le diremos que uno de los parametros es de tipo UDT_ARRAY

```
 create procedure spGenBK_Consultar_Masivo  
        @Codigos UDT_ARRAY READONLY
 as 
      select  * from GUIA_DETALLE_NACIONAL with (nolock)
      where rtrim(Guia_det_nro_ref) in (SELECT codigos FROM @Codigos)
 END
```

Como ves podemos enviar una tabla como parametro a un SP... ahora, como enviamos esa tabla desde C#?

C# Permite enviar un DataTable a un SP usando el tipo de datos Structured, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
        DataTable dtParam = new DataTable();
        dtParam.Columns.Add("Codigos");

        dtParam.Rows.Add("1010968487-1");
        dtParam.Rows.Add("1010968485-2");

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand SQLcomm = connection.CreateCommand();
            SQLcomm.Connection = connection;

            SQLcomm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Codigos", SqlDbType.Structured));

            SQLcomm.CommandText = "spGenBK_Consultar_Masivo";
            SQLcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SQLcomm.Connection = connection;

            SQLcomm.Parameters["@Codigos"].Value = dtParam;

            SQLcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

Eso es todo, espero se entienda.